# Check value common between rows

Tags: sql, algorithm

Let us have a table 'CODES' with two columns: Code | Date
(CODES (Code,Date))

I'm trying to figure out a query to extract all the DISTINCT codes that are paired at least once (but could be more) with every single distinct date avaiable.

Examples:

AA00 has every possible date

[image: AA00 has every possible date]

No code has all the dates

[image: No code has all the dates]

CC has all the dates, AA no longer does as we added 02/06/2016

[image: CC has all the dates, AA no longer does as we added 02/06/2016]

There could be codes with no date, or dates with no code.
Of course a date with no code, if unique, means that the output will be empty, as no code can have it and so no code will have all the dates.

I have tried for hours and I'm not even getting close....

Any idea?

Comment: Then post what you have tried along with sample data and desired output

Comment: I'll post sample data asap, given the simple nature of the tables I didn't think it was necessary. Grouped by date or otherwise, we just want all the distinct codes that are paired with all the avaiable dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will look for the Codes that have a total of unique dates in CODES that's not lower than the total of unique dates in CODES.

```sql
  select Code
  from CODES
  group by Code
  having count(distinct Date) >= (
    select count(distinct Date) 
    from CODES 
    where Date is not null
  )
```

The [HAVING](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) clause is standard SQL that can filter based an aggregate function (sum, count, avg, ...).

Comment: I am looking for the codes that are paired with each  and any avaiable distinct date, at least one time for each of them.

Comment: @Athamas changed the SQL.

Comment: @Athamas . . . This should work, assuming that no code has the same date repeated multiple times.

Comment: I see. In that case, the SQL has been changed again. If it has the same date repeated, the code will now only be selected if it has all the Dates.

Comment: I don't understand >=. How can it be > ?

Comment: It can't, but that won't matter now anyway ;)